# Build ASP.Net Website with MSBuild is different from Visual Studio build

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, msbuild

I have an old ASP.Net Website solution, that look like:

[image]

When I build the solution within the Visual Studio I get the following output:

```
------ Build started: Project: C:\...\XXXX\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

Validating Web Site
Building directory '/XXXX/App_Code/'.
Building directory '/XXXX/App_WebReference/'.
Building directory '/XXXX/js/'.
Building directory '/XXXX/msg/'.
Building directory '/XXXX/z_admin/'.
Building directory '/XXXX/z_emulationDialogs/'.
Building directory '/XXXX/'.
```

But when I build it with TFS (MSBuild task) or run the `msbuild.exe` with the solution I got another output:

```
Project "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\XXXX.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "debug|any cpu".
Project "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\XXXX.sln" (1) is building "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\XXXX.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).

Build:

  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\BarcodePrinter.dll" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\BarcodePrinter.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\IDAutomation.LinearBarCode.dll" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\IDAutomation.LinearBarCode.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\zxing.dll" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\zxing.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\BarcodePrinter.pdb" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\BarcodePrinter.pdb".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\zxing.pdb" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\zxing.pdb".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\zxing.xml" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\zxing.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\System.Net.Http.dll" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\System.Net.Http.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\System.Net.Http.xml" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\System.Net.Http.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.xml" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.xml" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\System.Web.Http.dll" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\System.Web.Http.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\System.Web.Http.xml" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\System.Web.Http.xml".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\TFSAgent\Agent01\_work\1\s\XXXX\bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.xml" to "..\XXXX\\Bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.xml".
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /XXXX -p ..\XXXX\ -u -f -d PrecompiledWeb\XXXX\
```

The problem that I'm not got all the DLLs after this build, if I make `publish` in the VS I got a lot of DLLs (e.g. `App_Code.dll`) that I do not get after TFS/MSBuild build.

I tried to add `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` but does not solve it.

So how can I build this project and prepare it to publish?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using locally? And which MSBuild version do you have on TFS?

Comment: I tried with Visual Studio 2017 in both (the project originally is 2012 but I tested in my VS 2017 and the build output is the same as 2012)

Comment: I checked again and suddenly I see `PreCompiledWeb` folder that generated by the build, all the DLLs exist there. I didn't notice it before! so I guess I should take the files from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an expected behavior. Cause you are trying to use MSBuild command to build the website project (metaproj). Then it creates a PrecompiledWeb folder and places the code in there.

> After creating a publish profile in Visual Studio the following are
>   created:
>
> 1) A publish profile (.pubxml file) under App_Data/PublishProfiles
>
> 2) A **website.publishproj** in the root of the website
>
> The purpose of the website.publishproj is to facilitate command line
>   publishing. Then you can try to use command like the following:
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>msbuild "C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio2015\WebSites\WebSite1\website.publishproj" /p:deployOnBuild=true /p:publishProfile=WebsiteTestDemo /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
> ```

Please use `website.publishproj` instead for MSBuild command and task, for more details info kindly take a look at the answer in this question: [Publish Artifacts for website goes to PrecompiledWeb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805055/publish-artifacts-for-website-goes-to-precompiledweb/43841775#43841775)

Comment: Thanks @Patrick! can I just take the files from the compiledWeb folder instead of create a `.pubxml` file?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yeah,  theoretically. You could do this since generated dlls are  just used for publish. And the `.pubxml` file:
1.Contains publish configuration settings and is consumed by the publishing process.
2.Can be modified to customize the build and publish process.  However, this is really not a common situation. We usually directly use vs build task for that kind of old ASP.Net Website solution. Suggest you double check and test in your side.

Comment: VS build task will give me other results rather than msbuild task?

Comment: There are almost the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667822/differences-between-visual-studio-build-step-and-msbuild-build-step However in your case, even you build locally through Visual Studio and MSBuild command line, you will also get different result. That's due to ASP.Net Website solution. Not related to task itself.

Comment: Thank you! I created the `pubxml` file and it works great.